# How to use $_GET[] in wordpress template?

Tags: php, wordpress, session, get

I try to use the $_GET[] array in a wordpress template page but I keep getting this error when I use it :

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in ... on line ...

If I comment every call to $_GET, the page displays without error.

How can I use the $_GET array in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us an example of how you're using it that you are certain causes this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using empty() incorrectly to check your $_GET[] variables, it can cause that error.

Look at this-> http://blog.ryanrampersad.com/2009/07/20/fatal-error-cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context/

Comment: I use it like this: if(isset($_GET('email')) && isset('recoverykey')) { ... } is it the same deal with isset() ?

Comment: It should be: if(isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['recoverykey']) {...} since $_GET is an array so you use square brackets to access keys.

Answer (score 0):

there is one plugin that can help you http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-registry/